# Gridster, wrong placement while adding widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridster

I'm using Gridster for one of my first Javascript projects and I've run into a problem.

When I add a widget to my grid, it doesn't go where I want, here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Florentde/J6quz/8/) of a sample of my project.

```
    $('#blockDroite').droppable({
        drop: function(e) {
            gridster.add_widget('<li class="widget"><div class="delete">X</div></li>', 1, 1);
        }
    });
```

When I drag and drop in a drop zone, a widget is created, but not at the correct position. Rather, it's placing it outside of the grid. When I move it manually it goes in the grid. When you add a new widget you can see it's behind the first one if you place it in the first column and row.

### Question

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I solved my problem, just forgot to add the "*gridster class*" to my **ul**. This "*gridster class*" is defined in the "*jquery.gridster.css*"

```
    <div id="blockDroite" class="gridster">Drop zone
```

Comment: Exactly my issue, Tried so many things. this saved my day . Thanks bro.